# UITextField adjusts Font Size To Fit height

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextField`:

```
let promoTextField: UITextField = {
     let textField = UITextField()
     textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("PromoCode", comment: "")
     textField.textAlignment = .center
     textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     textField.minimumFontSize = 17
     textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

     return textField
    }()
```

The `UITextField` height (only height) can be changed based device screen size. I need to automatically change font size based on `UITextField` hight. How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1    // your value
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true    
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
label.numberOfLines = 0
```